# Acumatica Generic Inquiry month-over-month sales totals

Tags: acumatica

Company I work for recently started using Acumatica (I'm also new to it) and I've begun to explore Generic Inquiries.

I have an inquiry that lists total sales for each month but I would like to add another column that calculates the change in percentage of the current row's monthly total with the previous row's monthly total.

Is something like this possible in a generic inquiry?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve desired behavior is to develop a custom inquiry screen. Very basic calculations can be done in Generic Inquiries on the line level, but nothing is available to perform cross-line comparisons or calculations.